# How to compare two List<string> and return non-matches (c#)

Tags: c#, string, list

.net fiddle:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/27wJLc

I have two lists of strings, the 'all' list and a list to compare, I then want to return the strings from the 'All' list that did not match:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> ratiodGids = new List<string>();
    List<string> allGids = new List<string>();
    List<string> notRatiodGids = new List<string>();

    allGids.Add("tom"); 
    allGids.Add("bob"); 
    allGids.Add("bill");    
    allGids.Add("tim"); 
    allGids.Add("sam"); 

    ratiodGids.Add("tom");  
    ratiodGids.Add("tim");  
    ratiodGids.Add("sam");  

    foreach(var g in ratiodGids)
    {
        if(!allGids.Contains(g))
        {
           notRatiodGids.Add(g);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(notRatiodGids.Count);

    foreach(var i in notRatiodGids)     
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I can re-type everything back to IEnumerable then use Intersect or Except, but that will take some work. So I wanted to see if it was possible with Lists before doing that.

With the code I have, the list returns nothing.  If I remove the '!' I get back tom, tim, sam.  So it works one way, but not the other.

UPDATE:  The result I want is just the strings from ratiodGids that don't exist in allGids. Order does not matter.  Also, I have tried using Exists(), Except(), Any(), Where() and they both give me the "List does not contain a method called blah ...".

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `LINQ` ..

Comment: Since your Lists are strings, you can just say `foreach(string g in ratioGrids)`. Same with `foreach(string i in notRatioGids)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use `Except()` on a `List` as well, because it implements [`IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) which derives from `IEnumerable`.

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, the Linq-methods are extension methods on `IEnumerable`. To use them, you have to add their namespace by adding: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I get the "List<string> does not contain a method called Excpet() ..."  Same with Where, Any and Exists.

Comment: @BattlFrog Did you add namespace?

Comment: `Except()` & co. are extension methods on `IEnumerable`. You just have to add the namespace for it. So on top of your class add: `using System.Linq;` and you're good to go. I'll add that to the answer for the next users ...

Comment: Dammit George, 46 seconds too late ;)

Comment: It's not matter, because it's your answer)

Comment: Missing namespace was the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Btw, here you have all of the methods in the namespace,. `Except`, `Intersect`, `Any`, `All`, `Average`, `First`, `Last`, and so on. Pure gold.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can compare two lists and return a new list with only the differences like so:

```
List<string> difference = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say it does.  if list1 is {1,2,3} and list2 is {2,3,4}, your result would be {1}, but a list with only the differences would be {1,4}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
var results = allGids.Where( a=> !ratiodGids.Contains(a))
```

if you want to get uniqe items from both lists then:

```
var results = allGids.Where( a=> !ratiodGids.Contains(a))
    .Union(ratiodGids.Where( a=> !allGids.Contains(a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
    foreach(var g in ratiodGids)
{
    if(!allGids.Contains(g))
    {
       notRatiodGids.Add(g);
    }
}
```

to this

```
    foreach(var g in allGids)
{
    if(!ratioGids.Contains(g))
    {
       notRatiodGids.Add(g);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, if listA = { A,B,C } and listB = { B,C,D } do you want your result to be { A,D }?  If so, here's one way:

```
var union = listA.Union(listB);
var intersection = listA.Intersect(listB);
var outside = union.Except(intersection);
```